# Htaccess ERROR500 issue

Tags: php, apache, http

My website is working well with xampp in localhost, when I added it online with filezilla, the pages: Homepage, About, Logging & Register works except when I try to register or login> I have a 500 error.
After searching in the error logs I get:

> AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to
> probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase
> the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I feel this is from my htacces files, but I can't see where, can you help me please?

```
-app
  -config
  -controllers
  -helpers
  -libraries
  -models
  -views
  -.htaccess
-public
 -css
 index.php
 -.htaccess
.htaccess
```

In /root >

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In /app > `Options -Indexes`

In /public >

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /shareposts/public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can you help me ? Thanks !

Comment: did you try to remove line `RewriteBase /shareposts/public` ?